# Rewrite structure of a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I need to make a lot of JSON files for a project. This JSON comes from Google Spreadsheets. Using [data-drive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-drive) I get JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "custom_id": 1,
  "another_thing": "pizza",
  "step_1_message": "msg",
  "step_1_hint": "hint",
  "step_1_intent": "intent",
  "step_2_message": "msg",
  "step_2_hint": "hint",
  "step_2_intent": "intent"
}
```

Now I want all the steps to from an object by itself. Like so:

```
{
  "custom_id": 1,
  "another_thing": "pizza",
  "steps": [
   {"step_id": 1, "message": "msg", hint: "hint", "intent": "intent"},
   {"step_id": 2, "message": "msg", hint: "hint", "intent": "intent"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: @JoelHernandez so advice him to try something before asking, otherwise he would not improve his programming skills.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I was trying for 2 days, but mostly with .match or indexOf which screwed up the iteration of the steps.

Comment: @JoelHernandez I would not ask it on SO if I didn't try it by myself first.

Comment: You're being downvoted because you're basically asking others to do your gruntwork for you. The accepted solution is just a `for ... in` with some basic regexp, both concepts you'd learn in your average intro to JS course. SO should be for when you get stuck because you're not sure what step to take, not because you want free labour.

Comment: @RamonGebben alright so why not post your efforts with the question?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Because this is my first SO question. I will do that next time I get stuck for more 6 hours. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is working solution:

```
var input = {
  "custom_id": 1,
  "another_thing": "pizza",
  "step_1_message": "msg",
  "step_1_hint": "hint",
  "step_1_intent": "intent",
  "step_2_message": "msg",
  "step_2_hint": "hint",
  "step_2_intent": "intent"
};
var output = {
    steps: []
};
for (var key in input) {
    var m = key.match(/step_([0-9]+)_(\w+)/);
    if (m) {
        var num = m[1];
        var name = m[2];
        if (!output.steps[num-1]) {
            output.steps[num-1] = {
                step_id: num
            };
        }
        output.steps[num-1][name] = input[key];
    } else {
        output[key] = input[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Slight modification needed to insert the step_id as required

    ```if (!output.steps[num-1]) {
        output.steps[num-1] = {};
    }```

should be

    ```if (!output.steps[num-1]) {
        output.steps[num-1] = {};
        output.steps[num-1].step_id = num;
    }```

Answer (score 0):

perlish.

try matching each key-value pair vs a regex to look for keys matching "step", than take this key-valuepairs and forEach match further for message, hint, etc. use these values as constructor-values for your Object to be. 
you will need a dynamic constructor in your objects class definition, if this jsons have different amounts of key-value pairs.